# PDE Method of Characteristics with -1 in the denominator of third term

Tags: characteristics, linear-pde

I want to solve the equation with characteristic terms

$$\frac{ds_0}{k_1x_2(s_3-s_0)}=\frac{ds_3}{k_2(s_0-s_3)}=\frac{dt}{-1}=\frac{dG}{0}$$

I have calculated $$c_1=G$$ from $$\frac{dG}{0}$$
And $$c_2=k_2s_0+k_1x_2s_3$$ from first two terms. But I am not able to calculate $$c_3$$ for $$G(t,s_0,s_3)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In your system of ODEs (Charpit-Lagrange I suppose) they are  seven symbols : $s_0,s_3, t, k_1,k_2,x_2,G$. Which are variables? Which are constants ? Which are functions of which variables ? Which are known ? Which are unknowns ? What are you looking for ?

Comment: Okay, I have added the variables now. I am stuck with third characteristic curve and it's solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{ds_0}{k_1x_2(s_3-s_0)}=\frac{ds_3}{k_2(s_0-s_3)}=\frac{dt}{-1}=\frac{dG}{0}$$

You correctly found the second characteristic equation :
$$k_2s_0+k_1x_2s_3=c_2\quad\implies\quad s_3=\frac{c_2-k_2s_0}{k_1x_2}$$
From $\frac{ds_0}{k_1x_2(s_3-s_0)}=\frac{dt}{-1}$ :
$$\frac{ds_0}{c_2-k_2s_0-k_1x_2s_0}=-dt$$
Solving leads to the third characteristic equation :
$$\bigg((k_2+k_1x_2)s_0-c_2 \bigg)e^{-(k_2+k_1x_2)t}=c_3$$
$$k_1x_2(s_0-s_3)e^{-(k_2+k_1x_2)t}=c_3$$